# ViewModel values empty on submit in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I Have two submits which should lead to different actions in controller but they arent passing any values. everything was working when there was one submit. Here is the view

### @ViewBag.Title

```
<table class="table">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.items.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.items[i].Id)
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.items[i].name)
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.items[i].name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.items[i].surname)
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.items[i].surname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.items[i].Selected)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteItems", "package", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Usuń" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("TransferItems", "package", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">

        <input type="submit" value="Przenieś" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}
```

and action in controller

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult TransferDevices(PackageItemsViewModel viewModel)
        {
```

...

the viewmodel values are null after submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two better options:

1) You can change submits to buttons and use javascript to make ajax call to your action(TransferDevices) instead of this.

2) You may use Ajax.ActionLink:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("TransferItems",
                 "package",
                 new AjaxOptions{
                           enctype = "multipart/form-data",                                 
                           anotherParameter=Model.anotherParameter,
                           HttpMethod="POST"
                 })
```

Answer (score 4):

When an HTML form is submitted, only fields inside that form tag are sent (unless the field has a `form` attribute refering to a *single* form).  Since none of your forms have any fields in them, nothing will ever get sent along with the submit.

I recommend putting everything inside one form and then useing javascript to change the action attribute to a value depending upon the button that was pressed.

Answer (score 2):

In the Razor syntax you're pointing to an action named "TransferItems". In your controller your action is named "TransferDevices". Perhaps it's just a simple typo?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the problem was that I had fields marked as `disabled` on my form. I removed the `disabled` attribute and it worked.